# Why is Rosetta Stone the wikipedia page on Ubuntu install?

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity

I've just done a clean install of Ubuntu 11.04. During the installation slide-show, I noticed that on the browser slide it displayed a segment of the [wikipedia page for Rosetta Stone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_stone). Any idea what the relevance is to Ubuntu?

Comment: Its just a page?

Comment: I don't believe it is just a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a web-page showing that there is a built-in web-browser called Firefox...

From [this bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu/+bug/862867) the representation of "web" was discussed - one proposal for later versions of ubuntu was the *One Laptop per Child*

[image]

From that bug report - it's going to be *interesting* if this "web" part of the slideshow will be updated to OLPC for 12.04.

---

If you were looking for a left field answer - the Ubiquity developers were presenting a subliminal message about [Launchpad's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Ltd.) Online translation tool called *Rosetta* aka "Rosetta Stone".

---

Either way I wouldnt read too much into this.

N.B. if you are interested in installing Rosetta Stone - according to [wineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=10043) the older versions of Rosetta works well in Wine.

Comment: Why would you argue it is just a random page? Seems a missed opportunity is that is the case.
(I have Rosetta Stone installed already and it work great!)

Comment: ... ok - a little more concrete answer!